# WX GUI FFT Sink Missing in GNC for Windows

Tags: wxpython, gnu, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, libyaml

I am new to GNU Radio and was focusing on training using GretScott's website.

I am running Windows 10. 
I installed 3.7.13.5/v1.6 from the [official site](http://www.gcndevelopment.com/gnuradio/downloads.htm) and noticed I was missing blocks. 
I decided to uninstall and install 3.8.0.0/v1.7

The instalation went well, though I also noticed a message in the command prompt after launch:

```
WARNING:gnuradio.grc.core.platform:Slow YAML loading (libyaml not available)
<<< Welcome to GNU Radio Companion 3.8.0.0 >>>

Block paths:
        C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.8\share\gnuradio\grc\blocks
```

I didn't give it much thought and proceeded to rummage through Companion. 
I noticed the blocks that were missing initially were now available. 
However, I no longer have any WX blocks.

Is there a way I can download these blocks as .yml and place them in the block path?

I have tried to install PyYAML from [github's link](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml) and then ran:

```
python setup.py install
```

I also ran:

```
pip install -U wxPython
```

No luck on either try, WX Blocks are still missing and I still get the (libyaml not available) message on command prompt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WX GUI is deprecated in GR 3.8
If you want to use 3.8, see https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR
Also take a look at https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Tutorials

Comment: Does QT have an FFT or Scope equivalent?

Comment: For version 3.8 and after, look at Instrumentation -> QT -> QT GUI Time Sink for a Scope style plot (amplitude vs time) and QT GUI Frequency Sink for an FFT plot (amplitude vs frequency). A good reference is https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Category:Block_Docs

Answer (score 0):

After the initial installation of GNU RC, you must then install the plugins for OSMOCOM and anything else you want.
I am using a Raspberry Pi.
In this, you go into the installation section and search for "GNURadio" and select everything with GNU Radio in the title.